# Is it possible to empty an array of null values but keep the keys unchanged in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have an array that is constructed like:

[image]

Currently, all the solutions I've tried are similar, such as:

```
            this.quantities = this.quantities.filter(e => e.length);
```

These however goes ahead and deletes out all the empty arrays (as desired) and re-keys the array down, as is normal behaviour (ant not desired), so 500, 1000, 5000 becomes 1, 2 & 3.

Is there a way to cull the empty arrays without re-keying? Because I am feeling the memory issues, especially as we get into a higher range.

Here's a snippet of the front-end view for the project:

[image: this.quantities array]

I understand that I can just refactor my code to use a reference object - but as is the nature with business - I don't have a lot of time to spare refactoring and lookups by these quantity keys are woven throughout the project.

I am using VueJS & this is my method:

```
this.quantities[ this.enter_qty ] = [];
    this.quantities[ this.enter_qty ][ 0 ] = {
    quantity: this.enter_qty,
    item_description: null,
    supplier_contact_id: null
};
//this.quantities = this.quantities.filter(e => e.length);
```

Comment: You want a sparse array?  like `this.quantities.forEach((v, i, a) => v.length || delete a[i]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to cull the empty arrays without re-keying?

<strike>Short answer: No, there isn't. At least not with arrays. In javascript (and a lot of other languages) an array must contain a value for every index.</strike>

**EDIT**: I was wrong. Arrays can have empty indexes. The solutions below should work anyways.

If I understand you correctly you maybe looking for a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). With Maps it is possible to delete key/value pairs without re-assigning the other values. So for your specific example you could assign each value to a map with the key (Object.keys()) but leave out those who are empty arrays. This way you keep the keys to every value without wasting memory.

Another solution would be to store your array as an object. So create an object with the keys of the array that do contain a non-empty array.

A very basic example for this would be:

```
let arrayOfArrays = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [],
    [],
    [1, 2],
    [],
    [3, 4, 5]
]

function cullArray(array) {
    let obj = {};

    for(let i of Object.keys(array)) {
        if(array[i].length !== 0) {
            obj[i] = array[i]
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: No, arrays in JavaScript can be sparse.  `new Array(1234567).map(z => console.log(z)).length` evaluates to `1234567` but logs nothing to the console.  (compare to `["a","b","c"].map(z => console.log(z)).length` which evaluates to `3` and logs `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"` to the console.)

Comment: @jcalz you're right. I did not know that, thanks! Kindof shows that Arrays are Objects afterall.

Comment: Using object.keys inside of my VueJS as a reference was the way to go, instead of foreach-ing the entire array. Sped things up dramatically with a tiny bit of refactor.

Answer (score 2):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'm just going to make some things up so I can test.  So you have a [sparse array](https://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html) and you'd like to maintain its sparseness when culling certain elements, without running into performance or memory issues.  Here's how I'd probably go about it:

```
Object.keys(sparseArray).forEach(
  k => filterCriterion(sparseArray[+k]) || delete sparseArray[+k]
);
```

where `sparseArray` is your sparse array and `filterCriterion()` is a function that returns `true` if the element should be kept and `false` if it should be culled.

Arrays in JavaScript are just objects, and the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method will only return those indices that are actually present, and will ignore the "holes" in the array.  Instead of `Object.keys(sparseArray).forEach()` you can also write `sparseArray.forEach()` directly, but the latter has some performance issues in [at least one popular browser](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1045391) because even though the callback is only called on non-holes, the implementation apparently still counts up from `0`.

Anyway, once you have the non-hole keys, the `filterCriterion(sparseArray[+k]) || delete sparseArray[+k]` will short-circuit if the filter criterion returns `true`, and otherwise it will call `delete` on the element in question which has the effect of poking a new hole in the array.

The `+` in `+k` is not strictly necessary at runtime, but TypeScript gets a bit unhappy about indexing into an array with the `string` elements of the `Object.keys()` result.  So turning `k` into `+k` explicitly coerces the string to a `number` which makes the compiler happy, even though the runtime will coerce that number back to a string to do the indexing.  So leave out the `+` if you want.

---

Let's test it:

```
const bigLength = 0xffffffff; // biggest possible array
const sparseArray = new Array<string[]>(bigLength);
// add ten elements
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sparseArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bigLength)] = 
      Math.random() < 0.5 ? [] : ["hello"];
}

console.log(sparseArray.length); // big length
console.log(Object.keys(sparseArray)); // only prints out up to ten keys, so it's sparse
```

Here we have a huge array in terms of `length`, but it only has (up to) ten elements.  Let's come up with a way to print this out, by just copying the non-holes to a new plain object and stringifying that:

```
function sparseArrayToObject<T>(arr: T[]): { [k: number]: T } {
    const ret: { [k: number]: T } = {};
    Object.keys(arr).sort().forEach(k => ret[+k] = arr[+k]);
    return ret;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(sparseArrayToObject(sparseArray)))
// {"769691472":["hello"],"1142335691":["hello"],"1663136124":[],
//  "1797609912":["hello"],"2067316024":["hello"],
//  "2440181807":["hello"],"2467909915":["hello"],
//  "2559556024":[],"2877791549":[],"3996739691":[]}
```

This prints out just the (up to) ten elements, which are at some random keys.  Now we'd like to cull the empty arrays (`[]`) and leave the non-empty ones (`["hello"]`).  Here we go:

```
// cull empty elements from sparse array

Object.keys(sparseArray).forEach(k => sparseArray[+k].length || delete sparseArray[+k]);
```

This takes almost no time in my environment, so the performance shouldn't be an issue.  If you switch that to `sparseArray.forEach((v, i, a) => v.length || delete a[i])` you will have a bad time waiting around for the compiler to count up to four billion, even though it only runs the callback for the non-holes.

Well, did it work?  Let's see:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(sparseArrayToObject(sparseArray)))
// {"769691472":["hello"],"1142335691":["hello"],"1797609912":["hello"],
//  "2067316024":["hello"],"2440181807":["hello"],"2467909915":["hello"]}
```

Looks good to me.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgSwOYBkCmYlQBYwLwwAMAHgGbkXkDcMA9LfMkmtDAA4gQQJwA2aMAIYAnYYICeAWABQoSLAhsRENAEFRE-DDBoA7jHVjxAHmjCEmANoBdAHwAKRKgxZsASioz6QgCY+YUBgwaPwAthhQEDKkIMIw9vywCFqENMnGMACMqTAIANR5bjAA3jIw5TCKymoa4pYAsoI4AHSkvCCx9o0tYmA+IKH2RQBUjM6YOG7WWt3Yzb39g0UZhM0ArDAA-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)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, super helpful. Accepted the other answer because it was an hour sooner and all I needed to solve my issue was to use Object.keys in the Vue template, rather than the entire array. But appreciate you taking the time to explain.